# How to get asynchronous calls using HtmlAgilityPack *In a Discord Bot*

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

using HtmlAgilityPack;

using Discord.Commands;

using static HorsemenBot.Modules.LadderPosition;

namespace HorsemenBot.Modules
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string TeamName = File.ReadAllText($@"C:\Users\anafa\OneDrive\Desktop\Horsemen Bot\TeamName.txt");
            var models = new List<Model>();
            var set = new Set();
            await set.LadderPosition(models);
            var teams = models.Where(x => x.TeamName.Equals($"{TeamName}"));

            foreach (var team in teams)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Team: { team.TeamName }\tPosition: {team.Position}\tTeamLink: {team.TeamLink}");
            }
        }
    }

    public class Model
    {
        public int Position { get; set; }
        public string TeamName { get; set; }
        public string TeamLink { get; set; }
        public string TeamLogo { get; set; }
        public string GroupLogo { get; set; }
        public string GroupTitle { get; set; }
        public int Wins { get; set; }
        public int Loses { get; set; }
        public int GamesPlayed { get; set; }
        public int MMR { get; set; }
        public int PointsScored { get; set; }
        public string Division { get; set; }
        public string ImageSource { get; set; }
        public int LadderPosition { get; set; }
    }

    [Name("Setting Team Name")]
    public class LadderPosition : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
    {
        [Group(""), Name("Ladder Position")]
        [RequireContext(ContextType.Guild)]
        public class Set : ModuleBase
        {
            [Command("ladder")]
            [Summary("Show your team's position on the ladder")]

            public async Task LadderPosition(List<Model> models)
            {

                using WebClient client = new WebClient();

                await Task.Delay(500);

                //await ReplyAsync("Downloading VRML data, please stand by...");

                string TeamName = File.ReadAllText($@"C:\Users\anafa\OneDrive\Desktop\Horsemen Bot\TeamName.txt");
                /*
                client.DownloadFile("https://vrmasterleague.com/EchoArena/Standings/", @"C:\Users\anafa\OneDrive\Desktop\Horsemen Bot\Ladder-1-100.txt");
                client.DownloadFile("https://vrmasterleague.com/EchoArena/Standings/?rankMin=101", @"C:\Users\anafa\OneDrive\Desktop\Horsemen Bot\Ladder-101-200.txt");
                client.DownloadFile("https://vrmasterleague.com/EchoArena/Standings/?rankMin=201", @"C:\Users\anafa\OneDrive\Desktop\Horsemen Bot\Ladder-201-300.txt");
                client.DownloadFile("https://vrmasterleague.com/EchoArena/Standings/?rankMin=301", @"C:\Users\anafa\OneDrive\Desktop\Horsemen Bot\Ladder-301-400.txt");
                client.DownloadFile("https://vrmasterleague.com/EchoArena/Standings/?rankMin=401", @"C:\Users\anafa\OneDrive\Desktop\Horsemen Bot\Ladder-401-500.txt");
                client.DownloadFile("https://vrmasterleague.com/EchoArena/Standings/?rankMin=501", @"C:\Users\anafa\OneDrive\Desktop\Horsemen Bot\Ladder-501-600.txt");
                client.DownloadFile("https://vrmasterleague.com/EchoArena/Standings/?rankMin=601", @"C:\Users\anafa\OneDrive\Desktop\Horsemen Bot\Ladder-601-700.txt");
                */

                await ReplyAsync($"VRML data downloaded, fetching **{TeamName}'s** results...");

                HtmlDocument document1 = new HtmlDocument();

                document1.Load(@"C:\Users\anafa\OneDrive\Desktop\Horsemen Bot\Ladder-1-100.txt");

                var table = document1.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[contains(@class, 'vrml_table_row')]").ToList().SkipLast(1);

                foreach (var t in table)
                {
                    var model = new Model
                    {
                        Position = int.Parse(t.SelectSingleNode("td[contains(@class, 'pos_cell')]").InnerText),
                        ImageSource = t.SelectSingleNode("td[contains(@class, 'div_cell')]/img").Attributes["src"].Value,
                        Division = t.SelectSingleNode("td[contains(@class, 'div_cell')]/img").Attributes["title"].Value,
                        TeamLink = t.SelectSingleNode("td[contains(@class, 'team_cell')]/a").Attributes["href"].Value,
                        TeamLogo = t.SelectSingleNode("td[contains(@class, 'team_cell')]/a/img").Attributes["src"].Value,
                        TeamName = t.SelectSingleNode("td/a/span[contains(@class, 'team_name')]").InnerText,
                        GroupLogo = t.SelectSingleNode("td[contains(@class, 'group_cell')]/img").Attributes["src"].Value,
                        GroupTitle = t.SelectSingleNode("td[contains(@class, 'group_cell')]/img").Attributes["title"].Value
                    };
                    models.Add(model);
                }

                await ReplyAsync(models.ToString());

                //await Task.Delay(500);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's what I've got so far.

Idea is that it reads this file,

```html
<tr class="vrml_table_row">
    <td class="pos_cell">59</td>
    <td class="div_cell"><img src="/images/div_gold_40.png" title="Gold" /></td>
    <td class="team_cell"><a href="/EchoArena/Teams/RHNkUmJMV1p5UEU90" class="team_link"><img src="/images/logos/teams/9b3b1917-a56b-40a3-80ee-52b1c9f31910.png" class="team_logo" /><span class="team_name">Echoholics</span></a></td>
    <td class="group_cell"><img src="/images/group_ame.png" class="group_logo" title="America East" /></td>
    <td class="gp_cell">14</td>
    <td class="win_cell">10</td>
    <td class="loss_cell">4</td>
    <td class="pts_cell">340</td>
    <td class="mmr_cell"><span>1200</span></td>
</tr>
<tr class="vrml_table_row">
    <td class="pos_cell">60</td>
    <td class="div_cell"><img src="/images/div_diamond_40.png" title="Diamond" /></td>
    <td class="team_cell"><a href="/EchoArena/Teams/cUJmVGlKajFGRlE90" class="team_link"><img src="/images/logos/teams/dff8310a-a429-4c60-af82-0333d530d22d.png" class="team_logo" /><span class="team_name">Horsemen</span></a></td>
    <td class="group_cell"><img src="/images/group_aa.png" class="group_logo" title="Oceania/Asia" /></td>
    <td class="gp_cell">10</td>
    <td class="win_cell">6</td>
    <td class="loss_cell">4</td>
    <td class="pts_cell">235</td>
    <td class="mmr_cell"><span>1200</span></td>
</tr>
<tr class="vrml_table_row">
    <td class="pos_cell">61</td>
    <td class="div_cell"><img src="/images/div_gold_40.png" title="Gold" /></td>
    <td class="team_cell"><a href="/EchoArena/Teams/UDd1dTJQRzBiRzQ90" class="team_link"><img src="/images/logos/teams/8eb6109e-f765-4d64-a766-cc5605a01ad0.png" class="team_logo" /><span class="team_name">Femboys</span></a></td>
    <td class="group_cell"><img src="/images/group_ame.png" class="group_logo" title="America East" /></td>
    <td class="gp_cell">12</td>
    <td class="win_cell">8</td>
    <td class="loss_cell">4</td>
    <td class="pts_cell">348</td>
    <td class="mmr_cell"><span>1200</span></td>
</tr>
```

and Pulls out just the Horsemen Stuff INSIDE a discord Bot Command.

Error:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0017  Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point.    Horsemen Bot    C:\Users\anafa\source\repos\Horsemen Bot\src\Modules\LadderShowModule.cs    18  Active

Still trying, nothing is working.

Comment: You have 2 (or more) `static ... Main(...)` methods.

Comment: So what do I do to fix this? I mean it's obvious I need to rename Main but do I just remove static?

Comment: It then tells me this:

Comment: This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    HorsemenBot.Services.StartupService.StartAsync() in StartupService.cs

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: 'No type reader found for type List`1, one must be specified'